# Parse multidimensional array from API

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am trying to parse data from from API to my view on my website.
When I put the script directly to the index , just for test , it return:

```
 array(2) 
 { 
    ["status"]=> int(1) 
    ["categories"]=> array(2) 
        { 
            [0]=> array(2) 
                { 
                    ["id"]=> string(1) "5" 
                    ["name"]=> string(19) "Pensionar / Veteran" 
                } 
                [1]=> array(2) 
                { 
                    ["id"]=> string(1) "6" 
                    ["name"]=> string(14) "Alta categorie" 
                } 
        } 
}
```

This is how my model looks like :

```
public function getPassengerCategories()
{
    try {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api_link");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $parsed_json = curl_exec($ch);
        $parsed_json = json_decode($parsed_json, true);

        $data = $parsed_json;

        return $data;
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

And my controller looks just like this:

```
function getPassengerCategories()
{
    $this->load->model('Curse_Interne_Model');
    $data = $this->Curse_Interne_Model->getPassengerCategories();

    foreach($data as $categories)
    {
        foreach ($categories as $category)
        {
            $html = $this->load->view("front/search_box.php", array(
                'categories' => $category
            ), true);
            echo json_encode(array("status" => 1, "html" => $html));
        }

    }
}
```

I try first to check if this array is parsed to the view, and that's how my view looks like:

```
<?php
    $data = array('categories' => $category);
    print('<pre>' . print_r($data) . '</pre>');

?>
```

The problem is that all it returns to the view is the following result:

```
Array ( [categories] => )

1
```

Any idea how to resolve this? Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iteration logic over `$data` is wrong. Here's your data:

```php
$data = [
  "status"     => 1,
  "categories" => [
       ["id" => 5, "name" => "Pensionar / Veteran"],
       ["id" => 6, "name" => "Alta categorie"],
  ]
]
```

Now if you want to iterate over categories and pass each one to a view:

```php
foreach ($data['categories'] as $category) {
    $html = $this->load->view('front/search_box', ['categories' => $category], true);

    echo json_encode(["status" => 1, "html" => $html]);
}
```

The overall logic seems wrong to me; you don't echo out a JSON response in a foreach loop. Anyway, whatever your logic is, you need to pay more attention to your data structure format.

Also, read these resources to improve your code:

- Use CodeIgniter's [Output class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/output.html) to generate JSON responses with proper headers
- [`$this->load->view()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) does not require `.php` extension
- Utilize [Requests for PHP](http://requests.ryanmccue.info/), instead of vanilla `curl_*` calls
- Use the more readable [`dd()`](https://github.com/larapack/dd) instead of `print_r()`
- [CodeIgniter model](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html) classes are mostly for database interactions, not service calls. Instead use a service class.